# Sending a list to Kafka producer using python

Tags: list, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a a few list that I am wanting to send through a Kafka producer.

```
listA [1,2,3]
listB ["cat", "dog", "fish"]
```

the producer sends the messages as bytes so I'm unsure how to properly set up the message so the list sends, when quotes are needed to send the message. This is what I currently have.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
for _ in range(1):
        print(producer.send('test', b'"worker_id": listA ,  "worker_name" : listB'))
```

this method just give me a SyntaxError. 
I've also tried this method below and I get a similar result

```
print(producer.send('test', b("worker_uuid": worker_uuid))
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered JSON encoding? If you configure your KafkaProducer w/ a value_serializer like so:

```
KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
```

then you should be able to send your lists directly like so:

```
producer.send('test', [1, 2, 3])
producer.send('test', ["cat", "dog", "fish"])
```

Consumers will need to be configured to decode via json as well. If you are using kafka-python, you might do something like:

```
KafkaConsumer(value_deserializer=lambda v: json.loads(v.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Json encoding is the exact method I decided to use.

Comment: Nice reference: https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/

Answer (score -1):

this is solved by first converting the list into byte arrays.

```
rList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr = bytes(rList)
print(arr)
```

the result is

```
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'
```